# A reduction formula for $\int_0^1 x^n/\sqrt{9 - x^2}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, radicals, reduction-formula

> Let $$I_n = \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{9 - x^2}}\,\mathrm dx$$
>
> Using integration, show that $$nI_n = 9(n - 1)nI_{n - 2} - 2\sqrt2$$

I've found that $\displaystyle I_0 = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$, but that's it.

I'm struggling to go any further. Anyone have any hints?

Comment: Well, from the last bit, $$I_n=\frac{9(n-1)nI_{n-2}-2 \sqrt{2}}{n}$$ and so you can find $I_2$.

Comment: Yeah, i figured that out as well, but how do you use integration by parts to show the required answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$I_n = \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{9 - x^2}}\,\mathrm dx= \int_0^1 x^{n-1}\cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt{9 - x^2}}\,\mathrm dx$$
Using Integration By Parts
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{9 - x^2}}\,\mathrm dx=\,\mathrm dv\iff-\sqrt{9-x^2}=v$$

$$x^{n-1}=u\iff (n-1)x^{n-2}\,\mathrm dx=\,\mathrm du$$

$$\begin{align}
I_n
&= -x^{n-1}\cdot\sqrt{9-x^2}\Bigg|_0^1+(n-1)\int_0^1x^{n-2}\sqrt{9-x^2}\,\mathrm dx\tag{1}\\
&= -2\sqrt2+(n-1)\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-2}(9-x^2)}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx\tag{2}\\
&= -2\sqrt2+9(n-1)\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-2}}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx-(n-1)\int_0^1\frac{x^{n}}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx\tag{3}\\
&= -2\sqrt2+9(n-1)I_{n-2}-(n-1)I_{n}\tag{4}\\
\end{align}$$

After rearrangement we get

> $$(n)I_{n} =9(n-1)I_{n-2} -2\sqrt2$$

Comment: Thank you so much :) :) :) Integrator

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:-**

$x=3\sin \theta \implies dx=3\cos\theta\ d\theta$

$\therefore \displaystyle\int\dfrac{x^n}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}dx=\displaystyle\int\dfrac{3^n\sin^n\theta \cos \theta}{\cos \theta}d\theta=3^n\displaystyle\int{\sin^n\theta }\ d\theta$

Comment: nice substitution but what happened to the limits?